# never seen a video that wasn't/hasn't been disliked

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

1. I've never seen a video on YouTube that **hasn't been disliked** by people.
2. I've never seen a video on YouTube that **wasn't disliked** by people.

Which one is correct?

Comment: There are scores of questions of this kind on the site and scores of answers. Which do you think is correct? And why do you think that the other one is not?

Comment: @Ronald Sole Scince you read this question, would you be so kind as to unswer it. And explain the difference in their meaning to the English learners.

Comment: We expect learners to do a little research themselves and show some effort. If they still have difficulties, they should explain what these are. If Mr X googles **past tense & present perfect**, he will find dozens of sites that illustrate and explain the differences.

Comment: @RonaldSole, my personal preference is for sentence (2), because, logically, it is *I've never seen a video on YouTube **in the past** that **wasn't disliked** by some people*. However, I'm not quite sure why sentence (1) sounds good, or even better to me than sentence (2) when I translate it into my own native language. Which do you think is more appropriate?

Comment: Please edit your post to include this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct and idiomatic. Which one you use really just depends on the context.

The use of **wasn't** would signify at some point or period in the past.

The use of **hasn't been** also refers to the past but implies that the dislike continues up until the present day.

Take a slightly different example to understand the difference.

Imagine that two people are talking about a a horse's poor performance in recent races.

If that horse is still racing, they might say: **His performance hasn't been very impressive**. That's to say, from a point in the past, possibly the start of the season, until now, the horse has performed poorly.

If that horse had been put out to stud, they might say: **His performance wasn't very impressive.** That's to say, they are speaking about a period in the past from the start of the season until the horse stopped racing - but NOT until the present because the horse is no longer racing. Its racing career is over.

In your examples, it could be any video at any time over any period. So it's not possible to say which people saw that video, when they saw it, whether they still dislike it or later changed their minds - and so on.

To use **wasn't** tells us that when they saw it, they disliked it.
To use **hasn't been** tells us both that they disliked it when they saw it AND implies that their dislike persists.

So you can use either verb tense. It just depends on what you want to convey.

Comment: What if we change terminative verb "to dislike" to a durative one (I suppose that the question relates to "to put a dislike", not to "to dislike" as "to feel antipathy"). For example: "I saw many videos on YouTube that have been adored by people" and "I saw many videos on YouTube that were adored by people". What would be the difference in these patterns?

Comment: @Ronal Sole, Does the same difference exist between 1) *I've never found a movie on YouTube that **has been** nominated for an Oscar*. 2) *I've never found a movie on YouTube that **was** nominated for an Oscar.*

Comment: These are the guidelines: We use the past simple for past events or actions which have no connection to the present.
We use the present perfect for actions which started in the past and are still happening now OR for finished actions which have a connection to the present.                                https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-or-past-simple.html

Answer (score 2):

However, I didn't find this on Stackexchange in the context of YouTube, where likes and dislikes are discrete actions rather than reactions.

So saying "I've never seen a video on YouTube that hasn't been disliked by people." means at least one person put a dislike on each one.

while saying "I've never seen a video on YouTube that wasn't disliked by people." suggests ALL the videos are disliked in general.

It's a subtle difference but perhaps that what he was asking?